# form data passing issue with MVC and Razor

Tags: c#, forms, razor

I'm using razor html and attempting to post data to a function.  I can get parts of the data to submit and go across just fine but other parts i can not.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reply", "api/Reply", new { ID = Model.ID, UserName = Model.Username }))
{
    <div id="mainArea" class="lightboxContent" style="display: block">
        <div class="lightboxText">
            <div class="responderTitleLeft">Select Profile:&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="responderFormFloat">
                <select name="profileSelector" class="select-style">
                    <option value="Select One" selected>Please Select Your Profile</option>
                    @foreach (var profile in Model.ProfileModels)
                    {
                        <option value="@profile.ProfileID">@profile.ScreenName</option>
                }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="responderActions">
                <div id="Reply" class="TwtiterReply">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <img src="/images/engage/actions/reply.png" onclick="toggle('ReplyArea')" title="Reply to message" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="ReplyArea" style="display: none;" class="responderForm">
                    <div class="responderTitle">Reply</div>
                    <textarea id="MessageEdit" name="Message" onkeyup="return characterCount(this)" onchange="postChange(this.id, 'messagePreview');" rows="4" cols="50" style="resize: none">@Model.Username</textarea>
                    <p id="counter"><strong><span id="charCount">140</span></strong> more characters available.</p>
                    <div class="lightboxButtonsBar">
                        <input type="button" onclick="toggle('mainArea')" tabindex="3" value="Reply" />
                        <input type="button" class="cancel" tabindex="4" value="Cancel" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="confirmArea" class="confirmationArea" style="display: none">
        <div class="warning">
            <p><strong>Warning:</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="warningMessage">
            <p>You are posting from @Model.ProfileModels with the message:</p>
            <div class="messagePreviewArea" data-form="Reply">
                <p>
                    <textarea id="messagePreview" readonly rows="4" cols="50" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: .9em; background-color: transparent; resize: none; border-color: #808080;"></textarea></p>
                <input type="submit" tabindex="3" value="Confirm" />
                <input type="button" onclick="toggle('mainArea')" tabindex="3" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

public UserProfile Reply(string ID, string UserName, FormCollection form)
        {
            var pSelector = form["profileSelector"];
            var message = form["Message"];



            ApiService msgserv = new ApiService();

            UserProfile up = UserProfile.GetFirst(new Guid(pSelector));

            messenger.Reply(up.key, UserName, ID, message);
            return up;
        }
```

what i'm looking to get out of this form (in order of how it's show) ID, and username (they are provided by the model and i get those no problem.)

The ones i'm having issues with is the profile selector and the text area with the name message.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to get a textarea and a select into a form?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the select is not providing the model with data is because its `name` property is not set to corresponing property name in the model. The same goes for the text area. Generally speaking, if you want the form submit to fill those property you use the 'strongly-typed' helper methods, such as DropdownFor and CheckBoxFor. Or you can manually wire those up, try setting the name of the select element to "SelectedProfile" and changing the Reply action to: Reply(string ID,string Username,string SelectedProfile, FormCollection form)

Answer (score 0):

To get from the textarea do something like this on your view `@Html.TextArea("messagePreview");` But I would recommend saving things in your model if you can.